# converting image and video data uri to base 64

Tags: html, html5-video

I was trying to encrypt image and video src by converting into base 64 encoded value. I had taken reference from https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri

Following is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video style="width: 640px; height: 360px;" onloadstart="" id="mediaplayer" oncontextmenu="return false;"  controls preload src="" poster=""/>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script> 
<script>
    // To access player after its creation through jQuery use:
    var videoSrc = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';
    var imageSrc = 'http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3html5.gif';
    var playerObj = $('#mediaplayer')[0];   
    var encodedSrc = btoa(playerObj.src);
    var decodedSrc = atob(encodedSrc);
    var playerObjPoster = playerObj.poster;
    console.log(decodedSrc);
    playerObj.src = "data:video/mp4;base64,"+btoa(videoSrc);
    //playerObj.src = videoSrc;
    playerObj.poster = 'data:image/gif;base64,'+btoa(imageSrc);
    //playerObj.poster = imageSrc;
</script>


</html>
```

On runtime image and video src is showing as encoded value but neither image and neither video is displayed on the web page.

Any suggesstions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work like this. You must base64 encode the actual contents of the file, not the path to the file. The link you used actually shows this in the example:

```
function getEncodedVideoString($type, $file) { 
   return 'data:video/' . $type . ';base64,' .     base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)); 
}
```

Currently what is happening is that the browser is trying to use the decoded value (whis is a URI) as the actual image or video data and of course it fails.

Comment: So, in my case there will be no purpose fulfilled by javascript btoa function ?

Comment: @antik - well if you can feed the actual image contents (e.g. by doing an Ajax call and passing the response to that function) then it will:)